# Django Validate Image or File With A Form Inside a Form

Tags: django, django-forms

Hello I'm having trouble here with multiple image with same field.
As far as I know in django tutorial they telling this.

```
  for f in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
     # do something (validate here maybe)
```

in which I don't quite get it. Like do i do manual validation? If so why?
Anyway there is another approach they give

```
  files = forms.FileField(widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True})
```

This one does not work in the way I want. It's self.cleaned_data['files'] only gives one output (There is a similar problem here) and django/multiupload was having a bug on my experience and sadly it was too slow to fix :(.

What I want was to validate each file and give errors to each via ImageField because I like it was validating a file versus I code it myself.

Thus I made a prototype code.

forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
   # validate each image here
   image = forms.ImageField()

class BaseForm(forms.Form):
   # first form
   ping = forms.CharField()

   #images = SomeThingMultipleFileField that will raise multiple errors each validate image.
   # since no option I decided to do that. below.
   # so for decoration that images is required.
   images = forms.ImageField()

   def handle(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      #custom function 
      image_list = []
      errors = []
      
      # validate each image in images via another form
      # if there is errors e.g this field is required will be append to errors = []
      for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
          data = ImageForm(image)
          
          if data.is_valid():
             image_list.append(data.cleaned_data['image'])
             
          else:
             errors.append(data.errors)
     if errors:
          # raise errors
     # return the data
```

views.py

```
def base(request):
   # this is an api
   # expected input should be from the code or format
   # {'ping': 'test', 'images': 1.jpg, 'images': 2.jpg}
   # This is not the actual view code.

   data = forms.BaseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   if data.is_valid():
      value = data.handle(request)
      return JSONResponse({'data': value})
   return JSONResponse({'errors': data.errors})
```

Not elegant to be honest but having trouble now and no more options I can think off but that.
The problem in my code is that

```
data = ImageForm(image)
```

does not reading the file thus image_list is always empty

1. So anyone can help me here?. Im stuck
2. Any better approach?
3. I wonder also for a general error like if one image is not valid it triggers like {'files': 'One of the images is not valid.'}

Comment: anyway i can do it clean_images, but for that purpose in the handle.

Answer (score 0):

so far, I tested again so my bad
it seems it requires the format of data, files in ordinary forms.
in order to do so.

forms.py

```
... # previous code
# data = ImageForm(image) , old code
data = ImageForm({}, {'image': image})
```

in this way,it fills up the default QueryDict: {}, MultiValueDict in the args

Number 3 can be answered.
instead of

```
# previous code
else:
  errors.append(error)
```

now should be

```
   raise ValidationError(_('Your error'))
```

Any Better approach?
Not much I can think off sadly. So anyone stumble here. feel free to comment. Much appreciated for the help.